Use the subclass of a usercontrol as a base class for new usercontrols
I want to create a "base" user control that will have some properties and events that i want to use in all my user controls that derive from that "UserControlBase".
That UserControlBase should also contain a FlowLayoutPanel, docked to the top and classes that derive from "UserControlBase" should be able to add content to that FlowLayoutPanel in VisualStudio Designer. But even setting the modifier of the flowLayoutPanel1 to public does not let me add Buttons or other Controls to the FlowLayoutPanel.
There is no code I can show as I have no idea where to look and I think/hope its a setting or attribute I have to add/set in the UserControlBase class... Can someone give me a hint?

You can subsclass FlowLayoutPanel and put your methods there. Then multiple of custom controls should be editable in winforms designer without much effort. But I suggest you to rethink your design and rather separate view from the logic. In WPF it's called MVVM. In short: instead of keeping your data in lets say ListBox and using its instance in every method that needs access or edit data, you'll have List<Item>, which is much easier to use everywhere and can be bound to anything in the view.

This walkthrough mentions that FlowLayoutPanel does not support Visual inheritance.

It seems that Ralf is right, FlowLayoutPanel stays in readonly mode when I followed shingo's link to hans passants answer and adjusted it to use a FlowLayoutPanel instead of a ListView...
